# How to set properties of destination vc on segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (myArray==NULL) {
        NSLog(@"its empty");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"not empty ");
    }

    filterViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSString *string1 = myArray;
    NSString *asd =@"asd";
    destViewController.searchText =myString;
    destViewController.myLabel.text=myString;
    destViewController.deneme4=myString;
}
```

this is my segue method.i imported and even erased the line where i check for segue identifier.

i initalized myString and successfully set it to another string where i segue and printed it with NSLog but i can't segue the same text to a TextView or even Label.

Where am i doing wrong?

My ultimate goal was to segue the content of my array where i fill it with this code

```
cell.cellLabel.text =[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

the content is right and not null. I checked. How can i make the content of this array to the text of textview.
Thnx

Comment: It's probably because the label/ textview hasn't yet been instantiated because the view hasn't loaded yet. Use `NSLog` or `po` in the debugger to check whether the label or textview objects are `nil` when you make your assignments.

Comment: @RichTolley that can't be true i think. Since i kinda back segue.

My initial screen has this label and textview and when the user click a button it goes the problemed view controller and another button get the user back to the original view controller where it contains label and textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, and you shouldn't, try to alter another view controller's views. That's bad design, and frequently doesn't work. You should treat a view controller's views as private to the view controller.

You have the right idea setting up string properties in the destination view controller and setting those. Then in the destination view controller's viewWillAppear:animated method, install the text into the views as desired.

Comment: how simple but yet how effective.I feel ashamed to not being able to try that... Thnx man

Comment: @danh, the destination view controller's views are **NOT** loaded when prepareForSegue is called.

Comment: Sorry, I'll delete it.  Guess I should have tried it before commenting.